# How can i get Friends Birthday and User Birthday on facebook in Ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

i want to get the user and friends birthday on my application.

i am trying to retrieve birthday data of facebook friends, but it's returning null. I'm using this code:

```
- (IBAction)login_click:(id)sender
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday",@"friends_birthday"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 // Process error
                 NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
             }
             else if (result.isCancelled)
             {
                 // Handle cancellations
                 NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
             }
             else
             {
                NSLog(@"Login successfull");
                [self fetchUserInfo];
              }
             }
         }];
}


-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name,link,first_name, last_name, picture, email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
              NSLog(@"result : %@",result);
              NSLog(@"user birthday : %@",[result valueForKey:@"birthday"]);
              NSLog(@"friends Birthday : %@",[result valueForKey:@"friends_birthday"]);
             }
         }];

    }
}
```

But user Birthday and friends birthday are return NULL

Answer (score 1):

The `friends_*` have been deprecated with the introduction of the v2.0 of the Graph API. So you can't get them anymore. Furthermore, `/me/friends` will only return those friends which are also using your app.

Also, you try to request some fields which you don't gather the permissions for, which will not work as well.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Hello @Tobi you are right but give me solution of how can i get birthday.

Comment: Solution: **It is not possible**

Comment: But some other application give the age of user

Comment: What has that to do with your actual question? You can get the birthday of the user, but not from his friends. And, to be frank, who needs the 10.000th birthday calendar application?

Comment: sorry @Tobi but i can display the age calculating birthday.facebook does not provide directly age so i have calculate the age.

Comment: i want to get login user birthday and his friends birthday.

Comment: It's perfectly clear that you can calculate the user's age from his brithday. The third time now: You can't get the birthdays of his friends. Read the docs!